# Parse JSON with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON response with jQuery but it's not working.
This the response I'm getting from the server:

```
[{"id":4,"targetUser":2},{"id":5,"targetUser":2}]
```

What I want to do is append the targetUser and id to a #box:

```
$.get(cometQuery(), function(data){
    var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $("#box").append(key + ": " + val);
    });
});
```

The server is actually rendering a Java ArrayList, so there could be more than one record.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$.each()`, you forgot to provide `resp` instead of `data`:

```
$.each(resp, function(key, val) {
    $("#box").append(key + ": " + val);
});
```

Comment: Also: instead of using `$.get()`, you might just use `$.getJSON()` instead, which would have avoided your difficulty to begin with.

Comment: Using getJSON was a good idea, thanks! But I'm having a probleam with the each, because I'm actually parsing a list of objects on the server side, so my actual data is one layer deeper, and the key and value return O and Object. If i only return one result (and not in a list) it does work. Any idea?

Comment: Can you use Firebug or a similar tool to post the server's response to the JSON request?  Do you mean to say that the response from the server (that doesn't work) is `[{"O":"Object"},{"O":"Object"},...]`?

Comment: Yes, that is the kind of response I'm getting from the server, it's sending an object list, and not one single object. (I've updated my post with the server response)

Comment: Try: `$.each(resp, function(v) {$("#box").append(v["id"]+ ": " + v["targetUser"]);});`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I tried v.id and v.targetUser too, but still nothing

Comment: My mistake - forgot how jQuery works with lists.  `$.each(resp, function(i,v) {$("#box").append(v["id"]+ ": " + v["targetUser"]);});`

Comment: That did it, thnks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You are iterating over `data` with your `$.each` call when in fact your should be going through the parsed `resp` object. That is, you want:

```
$.each(resp, function(key, val) {
    $("#box").append(key + ": " + val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be this?  The object gets stored in resp.

```
$.each(resp, function(key,val){...});
```